# Kafka Spark Scala Cassandra Compatible Versions

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cassandra, apache-kafka

I am trying to create an application using Apache Kafka,Saprk,Scala and Cassandra.
But I am facing a lot of issues in getting the right cmpatible versions of these tools.

Can someone please let me know which versions should I use?

Thanks in Advance..

Comment: Please add which versions you're using and how your `pom.xml` looks like.

Comment: I was using Spark 2.2 , Kafka 0.11,scala 2.11, but faced a lot of issues while creating the API's.

That is why I am asking from which versions should I start now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the list of versions for libraries which we've used:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
        <version>0.10.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>kafka_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>0.10.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cassandra</groupId>
        <artifactId>apache-cassandra</artifactId>
        <version>3.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.datastax.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-cassandra-connector_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

The main problem which you will face with compatibility is different scala versions (2.10.* or 2.11.*). You will have to look after that and see that all of the dependencies use the same scala version. I think you can update without any doubts all versions to the latest just if you take care about the same scala versions everywhere.

Here is also code sample which will help you with start:

```
       public static void main(String[] args) throws   InterruptedException {
           JavaStreamingContext jssc = new JavaStreamingContext(getSparkConfiguration(), Durations.seconds(5));

           JavaInputDStream<ConsumerRecord<String, LoggingEvent>> messages  =
            KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(
                    jssc,
                    LocationStrategies.PreferConsistent(),
                    ConsumerStrategies.<String, LoggingEvent>Subscribe(Arrays.asList("some_topic"), getKafkaParams("localhost:9092", "some_logging_group))
            );

           JavaDStream<LoggingEvent> loggingRecords = messages.map(
            (Function<ConsumerRecord<String, LoggingEvent>, LoggingEvent>) message -> message.value()
    );

             CassandraStreamingJavaUtil.javaFunctions(loggingRecords).writerBuilder("some_space", "some_table",
                  CassandraJavaUtil.mapToRow(LoggingEvent.class)).saveToCassandra();

          jssc.start();
          jssc.awaitTermination();
}
```

Mapping in the connector is done by mapping fields in the class with table columns.

For setup we've used ansible and distribution versions for archives were the same as in the library dependency list.

Comment: <cough>scala</cough> :-).

Answer (score 0):

In case you are interested in the sbt version

```
libraryDependencies ++= {

  val sparkV = "2.1.0"
  val cassandraV = "2.0.0-M3"

  Seq(
    "org.apache.spark"      %% "spark-core" % sparkV,
    "org.apache.spark"      %% "spark-streaming" % sparkV,
    "org.apache.spark"      %% "spark-streaming-kafka-0-10" % sparkV,
    "org.apache.spark"      %% "spark-sql-kafka-0-10" % sparkV,
    "org.apache.spark"      %% "spark-sql" % sparkV,
    "org.apache.spark"      %% "spark-hive" % sparkV,
    "com.datastax.spark"    %% "spark-cassandra-connector" % cassandraV,
    "com.datastax.cassandra" % "cassandra-driver-core" % "3.2.0",
    "org.rogach"            %% "scallop" % "2.1.2"
  )

}
```

Comment: And scala version is 2.11.8 for the dependencies above.